# Frattini sugroup and normal subgroup

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, sylow-theory, frattini-subgroup

For any group $G$, let $\Phi(G)$ denote the Frattini subgroup of $G$.

Let $G$ be a finite group, such that $\dfrac{G}{\Phi(G) } \cong K \times \mathbb{Z}_{p}$, where $p$ is prime number.

Prove that if $ p \nmid |K|$ then there exists a normal subgroup $L$ of $G$, ($ L \trianglelefteq G$) such that for some $n \in \mathbb{N}$, $G \cong L \times \mathbb{Z}_{p^n}$, and $\dfrac{L}{\Phi(L) } \cong K$.

I think we have: for a finite group $G$, $|G/\Phi(G)|$ is divisible by all primes $p$ dividing $|G|$. It uses the Schur-Zassenhaus Theorem.

First note that each Sylow $p$-subgroup $P$ of $\Phi(G)$ is normal in $G$. (So, in particular, $\Phi(G)$ is nilpotent.) To see that, we have $G = \Phi(G)N_G(P)$ by the Frattini Argument, and then by the fact that $\Phi(G)$ consists of the non-generators of $G$, we have $G = N_G(P)$.

Now if there is a prime $p$ dividing $|G|$ but not dividing $|G/\Phi(G)|$, then $\Phi(G)$ contains a Sylow $p$-subgroup $P$ of $G$ and $P \unlhd G$. So, by the Schur-Zassenhaus Theorem, $P$ has a complement $H$ in $G$. Let $M$ be a maximal subgroup of $G$ containing $H$. Then $p$ divides $|G:M|$ and hence $p$ divides $|G/\Phi(G)|$, contradiction.

Comment: Welcome to math.SE. We generally discourage posts that simply quote an exercise or problem (particularly as it reads as if you were assigning *us* homework, or ordering us around). Instead, we encourage you to provide *context* (where did you encounter this problem? What is your background knowledge in the topic?) and information about what you have attempted or where and why you are stuck. This will allow people to give answers that are suitable to your situation. Otherwise, you will find the post downvoted and even closed.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin  I think we can use Schur–Zassenhaus theorem and Frattini's argument .

Comment: Again, please include the relevant information *in the post itself*, and explain exactly what your issues are instead of issuing orders to the audience, as you are currently doing.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin . Yes I edited my question.

Comment: On top of it, crossposted [to math.overflow](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/356922/frattini-sugroup-and-normal-subgroup). It is almost *never* a good idea to post the same question to both sides, and it is definitely **not** a good idea to do so simultaneously. The sites have different missions and different levels. The only time cross-posting is appropriate is if, after being on one site for a while and receiving no answer, it is then posted on the other. And when doing so, a clear indication that the post appears in both (by cross-linking) is a must to prevent duplication of effort.

Answer (score 1):

I will write $G/\Phi(G) \cong K \times P$, with $P \cong C_p$; i.e. $P$ is cyclic of prime order $p$.

Now $\Phi(G)$ is nilpotent, so we have $\Phi(G) = M \times Q$ with $M$ a $p'$-group and $Q$ a $p$-group. (A finite  $p'$-group is defined to be one in which the order is not divisible by the prime $p$.)

Let $J$ be the inverse image of $K$ in  $G$. Then $J$ has the normal Sylow $p$-subgroup $Q$ and so, by the Schur-Zassenhaus theorem,  it has a $p$-complement $L$ (i.e. $QL=J$ and $Q \cap L = \{1\}$), and all $p$-complements of $Q$ in $J$ are conjugate in $J$.

Since $M$ is a normal $p'$-subgroup of $J$, we have  $M \le L$ and $L/M \cong K$. Note that $L$ is also a $p$-complement in $G$.

Now applying the Frattini argument to the $p$-complement $L$ in the normal subgroup $J = LQ$ of $G$, we get $G = N_G(L)LQ = N_G(L)Q$, and since $Q \le \Phi(G)$, this gives $G=N_G(L)$, so $L \lhd G$.

Similarly, let $S$ be the inverse image of $P$ in $G$, and let $R \in {\rm Syl_p}(S)$ (and hence $R \in {\rm Syl}_p(G)$). So $Q < R$, with $Q/R \cong P$. Applying the Frattini argument to the Sylow $p$-subgroup $R$ of the normal subgroup $S=RM$ of $G$, we have $G = N_G(R)RM=N_G(R)M$, and since $M \le \Phi(G)$, this implies that $N_G(R) = R$, and so $R \lhd G$.

So we now have $G=LR$ with $L \cap R = \{1\}$, and hence $G = L \times R$ which (by a standard result) implies that
$\Phi(G) = \Phi(L) \times \Phi(R)$, and so $\Phi(L)=K$ and $\Phi(R)=Q$.

So $L/\Phi(L) \cong K$ and $R/\Phi(R) \cong P$, which proves the result. By a standard result this imples that $R$ is cyclic, which completes the proof.

Comment: Why inverse image of $K$ in $G/\Phi(G)$ has the normal Sylow $p$-subgroup $Q$ ?

Comment: Because $Q$ is a characteristic subgroup of $\Phi(G)$.

Comment: We know $G$ is nilpotent group then $G$ is the direct product of its Sylow subgroups .why we have $\Phi(G) = M \times Q$ with $M$ a $p'$-group and $Q$ a $p$-group ? I think it is true when $|\Phi(G)| =p^{'} × q$.

Comment: That follows immediately from the fact that $\Phi(G)$ is the direct product of its Sylow subgroups.

Comment: So why $| \phi(G) | =p^{'}q$ ?

Comment: Oh sorry, I think the problem is that you are not understanding what I mean by a $p'$-group. I mean a (finite) group whose order is not divisible by the prime $p$.

Comment: So it's possible that $M=\{0\}$ , now is your proof always true ? also why we have $p | | \phi(G) |$ ?

Comment: Yes it is possible that $|M|=1$ and it is possible that $|Q|=1$. I never said otherwise, so why are you asking?

Comment: I think when $|M|= 1$ proof is false. I don't know why $ p|| \phi (G) $ ?

Comment: If you think it is wrong then please point out the mistake. I never claimed that $p||\Phi(G)|$.

Comment: How we can proof $R/\Phi(R)$ is a cyclic $p$-group, so $R$ is cyclic ?

Comment: $K \times C_p \cong G/\Phi(G) = (L \times R)/(M \times Q) \cong L/M \times R/Q$, so $K \cong L/M$ and $C_p \cong R/\Phi(R)$.

Comment: $Q \subset \phi(G) $ so inverse image of Q is $\{0\}$ so we can't use Q .

Comment: We use Frattini argument to the p-complement of $L$ or  $L$ ?

Comment: I have written out the proof in more detail. If you think there is a mistake then please indicate exactly where the mistake is in the proof.

Answer (score 0):

Let $P \in {\rm Syl}_p(G)$ . we show that  $P \lhd G$ and cyclic .we know $P\Phi(G) \lhd G$ now with Frattini argument we have : $G =\Phi(G) P  N_G(P) = N_G(P)$ so $P \lhd G$ .

with Schur–Zassenhaus theorem , $P$  has a complement $L$ in $G$ then $G=LP$.let $\Phi(P) <  \Phi(G) \cap P$ (proper subgroup) , then $P$  has a maximal subgroup $M$ such that $P=M (\Phi(G) \cap P)$ then $G=LM$ and we have a contradiction so $\Phi(P) =  \Phi(G) \cap P$ and $P$ is cyclic because we have :$$\mathbb{Z_p}\cong \frac{P\phi(G)}{\phi(G)}\cong \frac{P}{\phi(G)\cap P}=\frac{P}{\phi(P)} $$ now we show $L \lhd G$ :

note that $[P,L] \le \phi(G)$ then $[P,L] \le \phi(P)$.  by coprime action property $P=[P,L] C_p(L) $ so $P=C_p(L) $ and $[P,L]=1$ then $L \lhd G$.

finally $\Phi(L) =  \Phi(G) \cap L$ and we have $
K \cong \frac{L}{\phi(L)}$